# Radical ideal of $(x,y^2)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

> How does one show that the radical of $(x,y^2)$ is $(x,y)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$?

I have no idea how to do, please help me.

Comment: Do you know the definition of radical of an ideal? After studying that, try proving first the containment $\sqrt{ (x,y^2) } \supseteq (x,y)$ and then $\subseteq$.

Comment: $(x,y)$ is maximal

Comment: $(x^2,xy,y^2)=(x,y)^2 \subsetneq (x,y^2) \subsetneq (x,y)$, then take radical.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Recall that the radical of an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is equal to the intersection of the primes containing $\mathfrak{a}$. Here, let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime containing $(x, y^2)$. Then $y^2 \in \mathfrak{p}$ implies $y \in \mathfrak{p}$. Can you finish it off from there?

Answer (score 21):

This is a longer (somewhat self contained), more general answer concerning the radical of any ideal generated by monomials. The answer to your question is **f)** of the proposition below. If you don't really care about all the proofs, just remember and use **f)**.

**Definitions:** $K$ will denote an arbitrary field; ideal generated by $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ will be denoted by $\langle f_1,\ldots,f_k\rangle$. $I\unlhd K[\mathbf{x}]$ is a *monomial ideal* if it is generated by monomials, i.e. $I=\langle m_1,\ldots,m_k\rangle$ for some monomials $m_i$. A monomial $m$ is *squarefree* if every variable in $m$ has coefficient $1$ (or $0$), i.e. $m$ is of the form $x_{j_1}\cdots x_{j_l}$. A *squarefree monomial ideal* is an ideal that is generated by square-free monomials. Let $\sqrt{~}$ be the map that sends a monomial to the product of its variables, i.e. $x_{j_1}^{a_1}\cdots x_{j_l}^{a_l}\mapsto x_{j_1}\cdots x_{j_l}$ when all $a_i\neq 0$. Notice that the $\mathrm{gcd}$ and $\mathrm{lcm}$ of monomials is again a monomial.

**Proposition: a)** If $\mathfrak{a}$ is a monomial ideal and $f=\sum_ic_in_i\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $c_i\in K\setminus\{0\}$ and $n_i$ are different monomials, then all $n_i\in\mathfrak{a}$.

**b)** A monomial ideal in $K[\mathbf{x}]$ is prime if and only if it is of the form $\langle x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_k}\rangle$, i.e. generated by variables.

**c)** The only maximal monomial ideal in $K[\mathbf{x}]$ is $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$, i.e. generated by all variables.

**d)** If $\mathfrak{a}_i,\mathfrak{b}$ are monomial ideals, then $(\sum_i\mathfrak{a}_i)\cap\mathfrak{b}=\sum_i(\mathfrak{a}_i\cap \mathfrak{b})$.

**e)** For monomial ideals, $\langle m_1,\ldots,m_s\rangle\cap\langle n_1,\ldots,n_t\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\langle m_i\rangle\cap\langle n_j\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\langle \mathrm{lcm}(m_i,n_j)\rangle$.

**f)** If $m_1,\ldots,m_s$ are monomials, then $$\sqrt{\langle m_1,\ldots,m_s\rangle} = \langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle.$$

**Proof: a)** If $\mathfrak{a}=\langle m_1,\ldots,m_k\rangle$ and $m_i$ monomials, then $f\in\mathfrak{a}$ is of the form $f=\sum_{j=1}^kh_j(\mathbf{x})m_j$, so every $n_i$ contains some $m_j$.

**b)** $(\Rightarrow):$ If $\mathfrak{a}=\langle m_1,\ldots,m_k\rangle$ is prime and $m_i$ is not a variable, i.e. $m_i=m_i'm_i''$, then either $m_i'\in\mathfrak{a}$ or $m_i''\in\mathfrak{a}$, so $m_i$ can be replaced as a generator by one of these. $(\Leftarrow):$ if $\mathfrak{a}=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_k\rangle,$ then $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a} \cong K[x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n]$ is a domain, so $\mathfrak{a}$ is prime.

**c)** A maximal ideal is always prime, so by b) it must be generated by variables. But $K[x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n]$ is a field only when $k=n$.

**d)** $(\supseteq)$ is trivially true for any ideals in any ring. $(\subseteq):$ By induction we can reduce the problem to two ideals. Let $f_1+f_2\in\mathfrak{b}$ with $f_i\in\mathfrak{a}_i$, $i=1,2$. By a), every monomial of $f_i$ is in $\mathfrak{a}_i$. If the same monomial occurs in both $f_1$ and $f_2$, say $c_1m$ is a term of $f_1$ and $c_2m$ is a term of $f_2$, then $m\in\mathfrak{a}_1,\mathfrak{a}_2$ so we can write $f_1+f_2=(f_1-c_1m)+(f_2+c_1m)$ with $f_1-c_1m\in\mathfrak{a}_1$ and $f_2+c_1m\in\mathfrak{a}_2$. Hence we may assume that the monomials in $f_1$ are different from those in $f_2$. By a) we conclude that each monomial in $f_1$ or $f_2$ belongs to $\mathfrak{b}$. Hence $f_1,f_2\in\mathfrak{b}$.

**e)** is a direct consequence of d), because in any ring we have $\langle m_1,\ldots,m_s\rangle=\langle m_1\rangle+\ldots+\langle m_s\rangle.$

**f)** Put $k_i:=(\text{greatest exponent of any variable in }m_i)\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. if $m_i=x_{j_1}^{a_1}\cdots x_{j_l}^{a_l}$ then $k_i=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_l\}$. Now put $k:=k_1+\cdots+k_s-s+1$. We have $\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle^k\subseteq \langle m_1,\ldots,m_s\rangle$, because every term of $\prod_{j=1}^k(f_{1,j}\sqrt{m_1}+\cdots+f_{s,j}\sqrt{m_s})$ has the form $f\sqrt{m_1}^{\beta_1}\cdots\sqrt{m_s}^{\beta_s}$ where $b_j\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $\beta_1+\cdots+\beta_s=k$, which means at least one $\beta_j\geq k_j$. Therefore
$$\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle^k\subseteq\langle m_1,\ldots,m_s\rangle\subseteq\langle\sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle/\sqrt{~},$$
$$\sqrt{\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle}\subseteq\sqrt{\langle m_1,\ldots,m_s\rangle}\subseteq\sqrt{\langle\sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle}.$$
Thus it remains to show that $\sqrt{\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle}=\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle$, i.e. that squarefree monomial ideals are radical.

If $\sqrt{m_1}=x_{j_1}\cdots x_{j_l}$, we have $\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle=\bigcap_{r=1}^l\langle x_{j_r},\sqrt{m_2},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle$, because by e),
$$\langle x_{j_1},\sqrt{m_2},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle\cap\langle x_{j_2},\sqrt{m_2},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle= \sum\sum\langle\mathrm{lcm}(\ast,\ast)\rangle= \langle x_{j_1}x_{j_2},\sqrt{m_2},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s} \rangle.$$
Next, $\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle=\bigcap_r\bigcap_{r'}\langle x_{j_r},x_{j_{r'}},\sqrt{m_3},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle$, and so on. Therefore $\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle = \bigcap_\lambda\mathfrak{p}_\lambda$ for some ideals $\mathfrak{p}_\lambda$, generated by variables. But $\mathfrak{p}_\lambda$ are prime by b), hence $\sqrt{\langle \sqrt{m_1},\ldots,\sqrt{m_s}\rangle} = \sqrt{\cap_\lambda\mathfrak{p}_\lambda}=\cap_\lambda\sqrt{\mathfrak{p}_\lambda}=\cap_\lambda\mathfrak{p}_\lambda$, since prime ideals are radical. $\blacksquare$

**Example:** we have $\sqrt{\langle x,y^2\rangle}=\langle \sqrt{x},\sqrt{y^2}\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\sqrt{\langle xy,xz,yz\rangle}=\langle xy,xz,yz\rangle$ and $\sqrt{\langle xy,(x-y)x\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle xy,x^2-xy\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle xy,x^2\rangle}=\langle xy,x\rangle=\langle x\rangle$. $\blacklozenge$

Comment: For the $\subseteq$ part of $\textbf{d)}$, don't we have immediately that every monomial in the sum $f_1+f_2$ is in $\frak b$, hence $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in $\frak b$? I'm not really seeing the argument you're making about if the same monomial occurs in both $f_1$ and $f_2$...

Answer (score 11):

**HINT** $\: $ Applying the basic laws $\  \rm r({\frak a}+{\frak b})\ =\ r(r({\frak a}) + r({\frak b}))\:,\ $ and $\rm \ \ r({\frak p}^n)\ =\ {\frak p}\:$ for prime $\frak p$

$\quad {\rm r}(x,y^2)\: =\: {\rm r}({\rm r}(x),{\rm r}(y^2))\: =\: {\rm r}(x,y)\: =\: (x,y)\ $ since $\:x,y,(x,y)$ are all prime in $\:\mathbb Q[x,y]\:.$

Comment: I'm interested in basic laws on the radical in any (commutative unital) ring. If $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ are any ideals, do the following hold: (1) $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}}\!=\!\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}\sqrt{\mathfrak{b}}\!=\! \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}\!\cap\!\sqrt{\mathfrak{b}}\!=\! \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}\!\cap\!\mathfrak{b}}$ (2) doesn't $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}^k}\!=\!\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ hold for any ideal?

Comment: @Leon There is a list of identities somewhere in Atiyah-Macdonald, although it probably isn't exhaustive.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly $(x,y)\subset r(x,y^2)$ and $1\notin r(x,y^2)$. Since $(x,y)$ is maximal, it is the radical of $(x,y^2)$.

[This is probably Andrea's argument; see his comment to the question.]