# Is the radical of a homogeneous ideal of a graded ring homogeneous?

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $S = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} S_n$ be a commutative graded ring.
Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal of $S$.
Let $J$ be the radical of $I$, i.e. $J = \{x \in S| x^n \in I$ for some $n > 0\}$.
Is $J$ a homogeneous ideal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [the radical of a monomial ideal is also monomial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125907/the-radical-of-a-monomial-ideal-is-also-monomial) The minor difference is that that post is concerned with the grading of polynomials.

Comment: @rschwieb I don't see how to derive an answer for my question from the one you linked.

Comment: To someone who voted to close, please explain the reason for the vote to close.

Comment: What that person is calling a "monomial ideal" is just a homogeneous ideal in the graded ring of polynomials.

Comment: @rschwieb But your answer is much longer than Sanchez'.

Comment: The answer I gave is similar except with details. Besides, it also proves it for $\mathbb{Z}$ graded rings. I see Sanchez's answer is fine for $\mathbb{N}$ graded rings.

Comment: @rschwieb Let $S = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$.
The OP of the other thread means by monomials elements of the form $x^a$.
So, for example, $(2x)$ is a homogeneous ideal, but not a monomial ideal of $S$.

Comment: @rschwieb: Sanchez's answer (which I presume is the answer which is currently selected) also works for $\mathbb{Z}$-graded rings, since any given element has only finitely many homogenous components.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Four years later, I have no idea why I thought it didn't work for $\Bbb Z$-grading. Maybe I thought there was something about powers of elements with negative grades that could interfere. I agree with you. \ _(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes. Let $x^n \in I$. Take the highest graded piece $x_k$ of $x$, then it's clear by looking at degrees that $x_k^n \in I$, i.e. $x_k \in J$. Now $x-x_k$ is again in $J$ so we can repeat the process to see that components of $x$ in each degree all lie in $J$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $x_{k}^{n}\in I$? I think that  $x^{n}=\sum_{i}u_{i}$, $u_{i}$ has degree i then compare the highest degree of this component to $x_{k}^{n}$, they have to be equal. Is that true?

Comment: For people who will chance upon this in the future: yes. Since $x^n_k$ is the degree-$n$ homogeneous part of $x^n \in I$, by the definition of a homogeneous ideal, $x^n_k \in I$.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury $x_k^n$ is homogeneous of degree-$nk$, no?

Comment: This proof isn't really constructive, since what we get from $x-x_k\in J$ is that there exists some *new* $\ell$ such that $(x-x_k)^\ell\in I$.

Answer (score 16):

I will take for granted the following fact two facts:

(1) A homogeneous ideal $I$ in $S$ is prime if and only if for all homogeneous elements $a,b\in S$ with $ab\in I$, either $a\in I$ or $b\in I$.

(2) An intersection of homogeneous ideals is homogeneous (this is obvious from the characterization of homogeneity as the property of containing all the homogeneous components of all elements).

Now, for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, we let $\mathfrak{p}^h$ denote the ideal of $S$ generated by the homogeneous elements of $\mathfrak{p}$. It is visibly homogeneous, and it is prime by (1). The radical of an ideal $I$ is the intersection of the prime ideals containing $I$, and if $I$ is homogeneous, this coincides with the intersection of all homogeneous prime ideals containing $I$. It is clear that, regardless of the homogeneity of $I$, the first intersection is contained in the second. Conversely, suppose that $a\in S$ lies in every homogeneous prime ideal containing $I$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is any prime containing $I$, then $\mathfrak{p}^h\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$ is a homogeneous prime which also contains $I$ (because it contains the homogeneous elements of $I$ and $I$ is generated by these elements by assumption). So $r\in\mathfrak{p}^h\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$. Thus $\sqrt{I}$ is homogeneous by (2).

Alternatively, if you're willing to invoke Zorn's lemma, which implies that every prime ideal is contained in a minimal prime ideal, then the radical of $I$ is the intersection of the prime ideals minimal over $I$, and since such a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ contains $\mathfrak{p}^h$, also a prime containing $I$, every prime ideal minimal over a homogeneous ideal like $I$ must be homogeneous itself.

Actually, the characterization of the radical of $I$ as the intersection of prime ideals containing $I$ already uses Zorn's lemma, so one might as well use the shorter, second argument...unless you want to avoid Zorn altogether, in which case my answer is inadmissible.

Comment: +1 This is nice. However, I prefer the Sanchez' answer.
This is just my personal taste.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, by any chance is part of your preference due to the fact that my answer uses the axiom of choice?

Comment: Sort of. Generally I prefer constructive proofs.

Comment: Yeah. I like Sanchez' proof a lot too.