# Primary decomposition of an ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

> Suppose $I$ is the ideal $(xy, yz, zx)$ in $R =\Bbb R[x, y, z]$. I want to compute the primary decomposition of $I$.

I have viewed many post on this topic, as I suspect, the primary decomposition of $I$ would be:

$$ (xy, yz, zx)= (x,y)\cap(x,z)\cap(y,z),$$

but I cannot show how.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{(A,BC)}=\sqrt{(A,B)}\cap \sqrt{(A,C)}$.

Comment: @JosephCurwen am I wrong, please more details. I could not understand the topic properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideal is radical and monomial, for the monomial ideals holds the formula 
$$\sqrt{(A,BC)}=\sqrt{(A,B)}\cap \sqrt{(A,C)}$$
with $A,B,C \in k[x,y,z]$.

Now you have 
$$(xy,yz,zx)=\sqrt{(xy,yz,zx)}=\sqrt{(xy,yz,z)}\cap \sqrt{(xy,yz,x)}=\sqrt{(xy,z)}\cap \sqrt{(yz,x)}=$$$$=\sqrt{(x,z)}\cap \sqrt{(y,z)}\cap \sqrt{(y,x)}\cap \sqrt{(z,x)}=(x,z)\cap (y,z) \cap (y,x)$$
and then your primary decomposition.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I am stacked in step 2.

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: How to know that $I$ is radical and monomial ??

Comment: I suppose that $A$, $B$, $C$ are monomial ideals, and not elements in $k[x,y,z]$. Furthermore, in this case a simpler formula works: $I = ((a) + J) \cap ((b) + J)$ with $I,J$ monomial ideals and $a,b$ coprime monomials.

Comment: @Alvaro $I$ is monomial because is generated by monomials and radical because this monomial generators are squarefree

Comment: If you need more explanations about radical of a monomial ideal I think this could be useful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125907/the-radical-of-a-monomial-ideal-is-also-monomial

Comment: @JosephCurwen Thanks for explanation.